# 2 Dimensional Array in Java Output

Tags: java

I'm having a hard time outputting the the average of each row in this array that I'm trying to run:

```
    int x, y, val;
    double sum=0, ave, sumtot;
    System.out.print("Enter rows: ");
    x = khel.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter columns: ");
    y = khel.nextInt();
    double[][] myArray = new double[x][y];
    val = x * y;
    System.out.print("Enter " + val + " numbers: ");
    for(int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<myArray[i].length; j++)
        {
            myArray[i][j] = khel.nextDouble();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("My Array Table:");
    for(int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<myArray[i].length; j++)
        {
            System.out.print("" + myArray[i][j] + "\t");
            sum = sum + myArray[i][j];
        }
        sumtot = sum;
        System.out.println("");
    }
    System.out.println("The sum of all numbers is " + sum + ".");
    ave = sum / val;
    System.out.println("The average of all numbers is " + ave + ".");
```

Hope you guys can help me with this.:)

Comment: what difficulties do you have?

Comment: I wanted to output the average of each row.

Comment: declare sum a local variable inside your second for loop but outside the inner of those for loops `sum/Array[i].length`. You don't even need that sumtot

Comment: Sorry if I was not specific enough. My output show like this: My Table:
6   6   6
7   7   7

The average for the first row is 6
The average for the second row is 7

Comment: @KhelBo Maybe you can tell us what difficulties are you facing? A quick glance on your codes and it seems ok.

Comment: The code is fine. But I wanted to add an output where it will show the average of each rows depending on the number of rows user inputs.

Comment: What's your input for the "6 6 6 7 7 7"? And what is the output you expect for that input?

Comment: The numbers are just example. It will change depending on what value the user inputs. What I want to really do is to accurately calculate the average of each row and output this in the screen. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try out is something like this (with slightly cleaned up code). If you need to store the data for averages of each row rather than just printing them on fly, you could add them into an array or arraylist.

```
double sum=0, ave;

int x = khel.nextInt();
int y = khel.nextInt(); // input for array sizes
int val = x * y;

double rowSum; // something to contain data

double[][] myArray = new double[x][y];

for(int i=0; i < myArray.length; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j < myArray[i].length; j++)
    {
        myArray[i][j] = khel.nextDouble(); // input for array content
    }
}

for(int i=0; i < myArray.length; i++)
{
    rowSum = 0; // reset value each row

    for(int j=0; j < myArray[i].length; j++)
    {

        System.out.print(myArray[i][j] + "\t");
        sum +=  myArray[i][j];

        rowSum += myArray[i][j]; // add value from array
    }
    System.out.println(rowSum / (double)myArray[i].length); // print average from each row

    System.out.println("");
}
System.out.println("The sum of all numbers is " + sum + ".");

// this is the average of the whole table
ave = sum / val; 
System.out.println("The average of all numbers is " + ave + ".");
```

Answer (score 0):

Review the logic of this and apply it in your code (assume that array[5][5] already has values)...

```
for( int row = 0; row < 5; row++ )
{
    int rowSum = 0;

    for( int column = 0; column < 5; column++ )
    {
        rowSum += array[row][column];
    }

    System.out.println( String.format( "Sum of values in row %d: %d", row, rowSum ) );
    System.out.println( String.format( "Average of values in row %d: %d\n", row, ( rowSum / 5 ) ) );
}
```

Comment: i tried adding the codes, but it doesn't seem to solve the problem yet. Or I am not sure where to place it. Can you help me?

Comment: You don't add this code, rather the logic behind it. What is the problem when you run your code?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to output the average per row, editing from what you current have. You can do this:

```
for(int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<myArray[i].length; j++)
    {
        rowSum += myArray[i][j];    //Calculate sum of each row
    }
    System.out.println("Avg for row " + (i+1) + ":" + rowSum/(double)myArray.length);
    rowSum = 0;     //reset value for calculation for next row 
}
```

---

Take note of where I placed the `println()` statement. Placing it after the inner loop will ensure it prints after all column values are added in each row.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it! Thank you for all your output guys!:) It drew closer to getting it right.:) Here's how I did it:

```
    int x, y, val, i, j, row=1;
    double sum=0, ave, rowSum;
    System.out.print("Enter rows: ");
    x = khel.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter columns: ");
    y = khel.nextInt();
    double[][] myArray = new double[x][y];
    val = x * y;
    System.out.print("Enter " + val + " numbers: ");
    for(i=0; i<myArray.length; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<myArray[i].length; j++)
        {
            myArray[i][j] = khel.nextDouble();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("My Array Table:");
    for(i=0; i<myArray.length; i++)
    {
        rowSum = 0;
        for(j=0; j<myArray[i].length; j++)
        {
            System.out.print("" + myArray[i][j] + "\t");
            sum = sum + myArray[i][j];
            rowSum = rowSum + myArray[i][j];
        }
        rowSum = rowSum / myArray[i].length;
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("The average of the row " + row + " is " + rowSum + ".");
        row++;
    }
    System.out.println("The sum of all numbers is " + sum + ".");
    ave = sum / val;
    System.out.println("The average of all numbers is " + ave + ".");
}
```

}

Your inputs helped me a lot. Thanks a bunch.:)